# Which Is the best way to show data on a table using Ajax and JQuery On ruby on rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Hi everyone I'm trying to display data inside of a table using AJAX and JQuery, as you can see in my code , I used a partial form to retrieve data (this work great) and then when the save button is clicked , the data is displayed without refresh the whole page, but I don't know how to display it inside of a table and also a jquery UI slide effect, sorry I'm new to rails and even worse to web development :D

Let me show you my code.

> create.js.erb

```
$('#new_location').remove();
$('#new_link').show();
$('#allsites').prepend('<%= escape_javascript(render(@location)).html_safe %>');
```

> _location.html.erb Partial file

```
  <tr>
    <td><%= location.name %></td>
    <td><%= location.address%></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', location %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_location_path(location) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', location, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>   
  </tr>
```

> Index.html.erb

```
<div class="hero-unit">
  <%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
</div>


<%= link_to 'New Location', new_location_path, id:"new_link", remote: true%>
<table class="table table-hover">  
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
   <div id="allsites"><%= render @locations%></div>   
</table>
```

> new.js.erb

```
$('#new_link').hide().after('<%= j render("form") %>');
```

> location_controller.rb

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @locations = Location.all
    @json = Location.all.to_gmaps4rails 
  end 

  def new
    @location = Location.new
  end

  def edit
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    #@location = Location.new(params[:location])
    @location = Location.create(params[:location])
     respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @location, notice: 'Location was successfully created.' }
        format.js   
    end
  end

def show
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @location }
    end
  end
  def update
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @location.update_attributes(params[:location])
        format.html { redirect_to @location, notice: 'Location was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @location.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
    @location.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to locations_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see on the secreenshots ajax it's fetching data and replacing it but still don't know how to display it.

[image: Adding a new record]
[image: New record saved and displayed immediately]
[image: Chrome's debugging tool]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a id "#" in the replaceWith selector. Remove "#" and try again $('table.table tbody') or assign the id="allsites" to your tbody and keep your jquery selector the same as your first post.

Answer (score 1):

- I would advice removing an extra `div` inside your table and adding `tbody` and `thead` for styling purposes, like this:

> Index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'New Location', new_location_path, id:"new_link", remote: true%>
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <%= render @locations%>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

- I would probably remove *prepend* and replace it with *replaceWith*

> create.js.erb

```
$('#new_location').remove();
$('#new_link').show();
$('#table.table tbody').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript(render(@location)).html_safe %>');
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I've made those changes that you suggest, but still not showing data without refresh, what about the `_location.html.erb` partial? Is there is something wrong on it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, I figure it out, a few days ago a saw an example of using collections on rails, so , I used this line in create_js.erb file `$('table.table tbody').prepend('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "location", :locals => { :location => @location } )) %>');` and then rendered the partial adding this line in index.html.erb file `<%= render :partial => 'locations/location', :collection => @locations %>`  I would like if is possible someone to explain me this, yeah it solves my issue but will be better to learn a little bit more. Copy and paste without knowing what is being copyed isn't a good practice